# how do I check if the selenium server is running using bash?

Tags: bash, selenium

How do i check if the selenium server is running using bash? I want to make sure the server has been started up and running? Maybe check if selenium is running on port 4444? How can I do using bash?

Comment: You can use `pgrep -fl selenium`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following URL to check the status:
http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/status

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by hitting the following URL:

"http://SELENIUM_SERVER_IP:4444/selenium-server/driver/?cmd=getLogMessages"

Use bash to hit that and it should return OK if selenium is up and running and an exception otherwise.